# Unknown database connections

Tags: sql-server, encryption

an audit has highlighted some (apparently) unencrypted connections on one of our 2 nodes availability groups.  The IP address (10.x.x.x) is the IP of the other  node in the AG. Does anyone know what the connections with NULL session_ID and (unknown) auth_scheme are?[image]

Comment: Are you asking question about highlighted connection or connections with session id in (85, 86)

Comment: AG nodes need to talk to each other (otherwise, how would they synchronize) using the endpoint. My guess is that those are the endpoint connections. They are not going through the same port as normal SQL traffic so I guess this is why they are not encrypted (to validate)

Answer (score 3):

These connections are most likely the HADR Endpoints for your Availability Group. If you include more columns in your **sys.dm_exec_connections** query (`protocol_type, client_tcp_port, local_tcp_port, num_reads` and `num_writes`) you should find:

- Both connections have a **protocol_type** of **Database Mirroring**
- One of the connections has a **client_tcp_port** value of 5022 (if you used the default port during AG setup), a high number for **num_writes** and a low number for **num_reads**. This connection is the one sending data to the other AG replica
- One of the connections has a **local_tcp_port** value of 5022 (if you used the default port during AG setup), a high number for **num_reads** and a low number for **num_writes**. This connection is the one receiving data from the other AG replica

If your findings match the above info, you can check **sys.database_mirroring_endpoints** and check the columns `is_encryption_enabled` and `encryption_algorithm_desc` to confirm that your HADR endpoints were created with encryption enabled.

Since the AG data connections don't use the normal SQL Server ports and don't operate as 'normal' connections, the `session_id` column is *NULL* for these connections, and they won't use normal encrypted connections, even if available. Instead, even on SQL Servers not configured for encryption, these HADR Endpoint connections are encrypted separately using the configuration of the HADR Endpoints.

From an auditing perspective, this can probably be dismissed as a false positive provided your HADR Endpoints have encryption enabled.

Reference: [Transport Security - Database Mirroring - Always On Availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/transport-security-database-mirroring-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15)